# Ghostscript PDF/A-2b conversion runs into CID 0 font error

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, pdfa

I am attempting to convert various pdf files to match PDF/A-2b compliance. I am using this command:

```
gswin64c -dPDFA=2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=output.pdf PDFA_def.ps cid0.pdf
```

with a default PDFA_def.ps file which uses ps_rgb.icc (although I don't think that affects this error).
This works for most files but upon trying to process this certain pdf, I get this error in ghostscript:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: A CIDFont uses CID 0, which is not legal for PDF/A, reverting to normal PDF output.
```

Opening up the pdf file in the free acrobat version, I found multiple fonts that were Type 1 (CID) and Identity-H. Following the documentation on https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#CIDFonts, I tried editing the cidfmap file to replace the fonts I found using downloaded ttf fonts, but I don't think that did anything. Using https://www.ilovepdf.com/convert-pdf-to-pdfa, I was able to successfully convert the file to pdfa/2-b, but the fonts in the converted file were the same (type 1 cid and identity-h).

I also checked the converted file using VeraPDF and the errors seemed to show that the file had never been converted to pdfa in the first place.

I am just getting started with ghostscript/pdf conversion things so I am not sure what the proper way to handle this is, or if I am headed in entirely the wrong direction. Is there a general way for ghostscript to handle pdf files with CID 0 type fonts so that they can be turned into PDFA/2-B compliant files? Is there some processing/preconversion I can do on this file to edit the fonts or something else to make it convertible? Or is the noncompliance for this file caused by something else?

The file is in Google drive here: [cid0.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5jK4Hc-tCGjZS0Bfkop2BtA-5sHYM5n/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try using the current version, 9.54.0, or wait a month and pick up the forthcoming release. In passing; You must set -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB, not just set the ProcessColorModel. Note that your file also sets overprint mode, which isn't legal in PDF/A and will be dropped if you set PDFACompatibilityPolicy to 1. Its not surprising that Vera told you the output file wasn't PDF/A, if you read the error message it says "reverting to normal PDF output"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however using 9.54.0 (as well as setting the sColorConversionStrategy flag) results in the same message with the CID 0 font.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you are out of luck, Ghostscript's pdfwrite device cannot convert that file to a PDF/A file, because it uses a CID of 0. The text would need to be re-encoded in order to produce a valid PDF/A file, and the device won't do that at this time.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would you happen to know if there is a way to re-encode the text in the pdf file? Or change the font type somehow?

Comment: Neither of these is trivial. CIDFonts can contain more than 255 glyphs per font so generally you would need to convert a single CIDFont into multiple regular fonts. It's not impossible but its quite hard. re-encoding the font would also be tricky. You would need to know if it has TrueType, type 1 or CFF outlines. Type 1 or CFF you would need to rewrite the font with the glyph description at CID 0 stored elsewhere, and then re-encode the text. For TrueType you would need to instead alter the CIDToGIDMap. Again possible, but hard to do.